# Get selected value in Select2 v4

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

This question is specifically aimed towards `Select2 v4`

How do I get the selected `Value` for a `Select2` dropdown?

I have tried the following:

```
jQuery('#Dropdown').val()

jQuery('#Dropdown').select2().val()
```

and neither seem to give me the Value of the selected element. I have made sure that there is a selected item when running this code.

Comment: What do you mean by ID of the selected element? Select has options, each option has value and title. Did you mean value?

Comment: @Shrike I believe I did

Answer (score 2):

select2 do not provide any direct method to get selected options attribute values. You need to get selected option element in select2 and then find its attribute ID:

```
jQuery('#Dropdown').select2().find(":selected").attr("id");
```

which can be narrowed down to:

```
jQuery("#Dropdown :selected").attr("id");
```

Comment: > jQuery('#Dropdown').select2() - 

I believe, that's not correct, it'll initialize a new instance

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#Dropdown').select2('data')[0].text;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="Dropdown">
    <option id="1">Value 1</option>
    <option id="2">Value 2</option>
</select>

$('#Dropdown').select2('data')[0].id; //to get the id
$('#Dropdown').select2('data')[0].text; //to get the value
```

**Notice the [0] after select2('data')?**

On Select2 v2 this is not needed it $('#Dropdown').select2('data').text;

Select2 v4 return an **array of objects named results**, so need to add [0]

Answer (score 1):

if you have such select:

```
<select class="select2-hidden-accessible" data-placeholder="Select a value" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

and "Option 1" item is selected.

```
var $select = $(".select2").parent().find("select"); // it's <select> element
var value = $select.val();
```

Then `$select.val()` will return "1" value for you.

Comment: ....I was looking for `input`, not `select`..... Whoops. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Select2 provides an `onselect` event where you can pass the event argument, from which the selected option can be derived.

```
$('.selectSports').on('select2:select', function(event) {
    event.params.data // returns you the selected item.
});
```

You can then do `if event.params.data.id == "your_target_id"` then do something

Answer (score 0):

If all you are really interested is in the value and not the id why not set the id value same as that of your value - since each value are unique anyway.

Then you can simply do -

```
jQuery('#Dropdown').val()
```

which returns the id but since our id is same as value we get the value and use it for further processing.

Note my select is an input -

```
<input class="text" type="text" name="select"  id="select">
$("#select").select2({
    data : dataSet
});
```

and dataSet is array of elements like

```
[
{id: "value1", text: "value1"},
{id: "value2", text: "value1", selected: "selected"}
]
```